# Testing JavaScript libraries with nodeunit - FileApi, substr undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodeunit

I wan to test my library with nodeunit, and I use `File` Object in it, on website everything is working (FileAPI is implemented there) but when I'm trying to test it with nodeunit i get an error:

`Fatal error: File is not defined`

I assume that I have to add:

```
var FileAPI = require('file-api');
var File = FileAPI.File;
```

at the begging of the code, but I don't need that when I include that library to website, how to deal with that?
To use nodeunit I had to add module.exports at the end, is it necessary as well? (code sample on github)

What's more, when I'm trying to test this code:
https://github.com/GeoSmartCity-CIP/gsc-client/blob/feature/upload-data-file/src/upload/upload.js

with this test:

```
var gsc = require('../../src/upload/upload');
var FileAPI = require('file-api');
var File = FileAPI.File;
var exports = exports || {};

exports.isFileTypeCorrect = function(test) {
  var file = new File('test.geojson');
  var asd = new gsc.upload.Data(file);
  test.ok(asd.isFileTypeCorrect(), 'this assertion should pass');
  test.done();
};
```

I'm getting `Fatal error: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined` error, what's the problem?
EDIT:
problem with substr is propably from isShapefileCorrect function, but still dont know why?

Answer (score 0):

`var asd = new gsc.upload.Data(file);` Isn't it asynchronous function? Then probably asd.isFileTypeCorrect() should be called inside upload callback. Also you defining isFileTypeCorrect function as module exports and call itself inside itself. Isnt it an infinite loop?

Comment: It's constructor of Data Object inside upload namespace.

Where I'm calling function inside itself? `exports.isFileTypeCorrect` is just a new test to run isn't it?

Comment: Ok, then var file, will be a buffer. Not a string. gsc.upload.Data takes argument of what type?

Comment: of File type 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-file
https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-api